How to log remote syslog/journal to per-host journals?
I am trying to setup a logging server using rsyslog. As clients I have machines that can use journald as well as legacy applications that can only use syslog. As such, there needs to exist a plain syslog endpoint.
I would like to store all logs as separate journals on the logging server in order to benefit from its advantages over regular syslog. How can I achieve this?
Things I have tried/thought about:

Using omfwd on the logging clients and imtcp+omjournal on the logging server: This seems to work, however, all journal entries are saved in the logging server's own journal and I cannot seem to send them to separate locations instead.
Using omfwd on the logging clients and omfile to dynamic files on the logging server and trying to pass those to imfile+omjournal: I think this should work, but I cannot seem to write a configuration file that achieves it.
Using omhttp on the logging clients in order to communicate with systemd-journal-remote: I have thought about this, but am not sure how to set this up.

